# Trigger automatic export to CSV while saving the Numbers Sheet

Tags: applescript, numbers, csv

Is it possible to `trigger` automatic CSV export of a `.numbers` file while saving / closing?

The thing is, I'd like to keep two versions of the same file. One with the `.numbers` extension, where you can have nice formatting, filtering, etc, and a pure `.csv` which is obviously more convenient to work with for programming purposes.

What is more, I don't want my co-worker to export the file by hand every time they change something because it will surely lead to a lot of sync errors and is a pain in the neck.

The best would be something like `On save trigger` connected with a certain `.numbers` document defined in AppleScript, but I am not sure if AS supports something like that.

In such a case, does anybody have any ideas on how to achieve such a goal?

Answer (score -1):

Specifically i have nothing but it seems like you might be able to use Automator to do something like that. You'd probably have to look into whatever communities there are for automator to see if we can get it triggered on save. At the very least I imagine you could have the script run timely like every hour or so so it's always updating potentially.

Source: [An Introduction To Using Mac Automator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTmZOh1GI3U) [YouTube]
Source: [Creating Useful Helper Actions For Mac Numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wjf1QHKHPpI) [YouTube]

Here's an example of one that does what you want... but backward you might be able to use that.

Source: [Making a standalone application to add data from CSV to Database](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2553-automator-for-mac-os-x-tutorial-and-examples#toc-anchor-011)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: oh come on bot !